# Unable to connect SQL Server from some computer

Tags: sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (OS: Windows Server 2019). It is running fine till yesterday. But suddenly I am not able to connect the database. I did not change anything, but still I check service status, ping that ip, port number, firewall, as well as firewall of local computer. Everything is ok, but unable to connect database (but also connect to server using remote desktop, no firewall issue). Interestingly some other computer can connect database normally (using SQL Server Management Studio 2018).

From yesterday, I try to find out the issue, but not getting any hints. If there is problem on server then no one will connect. If firewall block me (from both side), then I can not connect server.

Can any one please give some idea? Please...

**Update:**
I try to check port using: Test-NetConnection xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -Port 1433 (using PowerShell). But result is fail (But it successfully connect IP).

Attaching Error (SQL Server Management Studio 2018)

> Cannot connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> ---
>
> For help, click: https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-53-database-engine-error
>
> ---
>
> Error Number: 53
> Severity: 20
> State: 0
>
> ---
>
> Program Location:
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()
>
> ===================================
>
> The network path was not found

Comment: Have you tired to connect by IP and server name?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: If it's intermittent: https://mitchwheat.com/2019/04/12/sql-server-diagnosing-intermittent-connectivity-issues/

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect server using IP

Comment: Yes, I follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15 link step by step

Comment: Why getting fail result when test port? On server side firewall is open (because some pc connecting on database). On client side I added allow rule (Server IP) on firewall. Please give some idea.

Comment: Does the IP address and port connection test (`Test-NetConnection xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -Port 1433`) work on some machines but not others? Are the machines on different subnets? It could be a network firewall (not host) is blocking the connection.

Comment: Yes, port connection test work successfully on some machine on some clients. That machine belong on different subnet also. What to do? Just blocking port (But test success on IP). But this system working fine 2 days earlier, nothing install/update. How to open/enable port on local system(for out going traffic)?